# parsing array list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following input for the array list  :

```
[item II, model IX, brand XX]
```

the desired output is as follows:

```
[II, IX, XX]
```

I try the following:

```
int size = names.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(names);
            String d=Arrays.toString(names.get(i).split("\\s+"));

            System.out.println(d);}
```

the above code will return a string as follows, I am stuck on how to index the string, in this case, to take the second element in a simple way.

```
[item, II]

[model, IX]

[brand, XX]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String.split() method returns a String array. For example, `"item II".split("\\s+")` would return a String array like: {"item", "II"}. So, you can just call for the second item in the array returned by the split method.

```
String d = names.get(i).split("\\s+")[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Using streams:

```
package parsestring;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ParseOnSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("item II", "model IX", "brand XX"));

        List<String> values = names.stream()
                .map(name -> name.split(" ")[1])
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. After the split, which returns an array, you can index the second item.

```java
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("item II");
names.add("model IX");
names.add("brand XX");

List<String> secondNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String name : names) {
    String second = name.split("\\s+")[1];  // get second item
    secondNames.add(second);
}
```